npm soap(https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap) package - trying to access a local wsdl file
I am trying to use this node soap library to create soap client using local wsdl files. I tried lot of things, but still not able to create soap client and  make soap API calls.
Can someone please guide me on how to use a local wsdl file with this package to make soap API calls?
I tried in the below mentioned way:
const soap = require('soap');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

async function testRequest() {
    const wsdlPath = path.join(__dirname, 'wsdl/webservice/wsdl/test.wsdl');
    const url = `file:/${wsdlPath}`;
    console.log("URL:", url);
    const args = {
        capability: {
            release: {
                version: {
                    major: 1,
                    minor: 0
                }
            },
            authentication: 'md5-digest'
        }
    };

try {
    const client = await soap.createClientAsync(url);
    const response = await client.testRequestAsync(args);
    const result = response[0];
    console.warn("testRequest response: ", result);
    return result;
} catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Error in testRequest: ' + error.message);
}

}

You can call as a client of SOAP with a local WSDL file
const url = path.join(__dirname, 'test.wsdl');
const client = await soap.createClientAsync(url);

Demo
Overview http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx
WSDL URL
http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL


Addition and Subtraction Examples with this values

100 + 200 = 300
100 - 200 = -100

Save as demo.js
const soap = require('soap');
const path = require('path');
const url = path.join(__dirname, 'calculator.wsdl');
// const url = 'http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL';
const args = {
    intA: 9,
    intB: 3
};

async function performOperations() {
    try {
        const client = await soap.createClientAsync(url);
        
        // Perform Addition: 9 + 3 = 12
        const addResult = await client.AddAsync(args);
        console.log('Addition Result:', addResult[0]);

        // Perform Subtraction: 9 - 3 = 6
        const subtractResult = await client.SubtractAsync(args);
        console.log('Subtraction Result:', subtractResult[0]);

        // Perform Division: 9 / 3 = 3
        const divideResult = await client.DivideAsync(args);
        console.log('Division Result:', divideResult[0]);

        // Perform Multiplication: 9 * 3 = 27
        const multiplyResult = await client.MultiplyAsync(args);
        console.log('Multiplication Result:', multiplyResult[0]);
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
}

performOperations();

local WSDL
Open from
http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL

Save WSDL as calculator.wsdl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
      <s:element name="Add">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="intA" type="s:int" />
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="intB" type="s:int" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="AddResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="AddResult" type="s:int" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="Subtract">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="intA" type="s:int" />
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="intB" type="s:int" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="SubtractResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SubtractResult" type="s:int" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="Multiply">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="intA" type="s:int" />
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="intB" type="s:int" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="MultiplyResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="MultiplyResult" type="s:int" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="Divide">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="intA" type="s:int" />
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="intB" type="s:int" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="DivideResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="DivideResult" type="s:int" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="AddSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Add" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="AddSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AddResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="SubtractSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Subtract" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="SubtractSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SubtractResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="MultiplySoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Multiply" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="MultiplySoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:MultiplyResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="DivideSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Divide" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="DivideSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:DivideResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="CalculatorSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="Add">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Adds two integers. This is a test WebService. ©DNE Online</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:AddSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:AddSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Subtract">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:SubtractSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:SubtractSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Multiply">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:MultiplySoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:MultiplySoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Divide">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:DivideSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:DivideSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="CalculatorSoap" type="tns:CalculatorSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Add">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Add" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Subtract">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Subtract" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Multiply">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Multiply" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Divide">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Divide" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="CalculatorSoap12" type="tns:CalculatorSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Add">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Add" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Subtract">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Subtract" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Multiply">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Multiply" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Divide">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Divide" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="Calculator">
    <wsdl:port name="CalculatorSoap" binding="tns:CalculatorSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="CalculatorSoap12" binding="tns:CalculatorSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>

Install dependency
npm install soap

Run it
node demo.js

Result
4 Operations called with a correct results.

